# laravel dusk id selector

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

i need help in dusk 
i have this html code

```
<div class="MessageBoxButtonSection">
<button id="bot1-Msg1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm botTempo"> No</button>
<button id="bot2-Msg1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm botTempo"> Yes</button>
</div>
```

I wanna chose  ( yes ) 
how i can select it in dusk 
i try this one

```
 ->press('button[id=bot2-Msg1]')
```

but its not work

how solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use:

```
->press('button#bot2-Msg1')
```

or to make it shorter just:

```
->press('#bot2-Msg1')
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

use Just: 
`->press('Yes');`
thats work fine for me.